# Is there an accepted convention for the order of @property declaration attributes?

Tags: objective-c, properties

I tend to declare my property attributes in this order: Writability, Setter Semantics, Atomicity

For example:

```
@property (readwrite, strong, nonatomic) NSString *foo;
```

I'm just wondering if there's a generally-accepted convention among Objective-C developers? [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17) seem to be silent on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

You will see code, even from Apple, with them declared in different orders.  It makes no difference to the compiler, and since there are not a ton of them, it does not necessarily make the code any easier to read either.

Use whatever convention you like (including no-convention).

Answer (score 0):

Below is the clang corresponding source code. Xcode may generate code based on the enum order. So I think **there is no exactly convention order for this attributes**.

```
/// Represents one property declaration in an Objective-C interface.
///
/// For example:
/// \code{.mm}
/// \@property (assign, readwrite) int MyProperty;
/// \endcode
class ObjCPropertyDecl : public NamedDecl {
  public:
  enum PropertyAttributeKind {
    OBJC_PR_noattr    = 0x00,
    OBJC_PR_readonly  = 0x01,
    OBJC_PR_getter    = 0x02,
    OBJC_PR_assign    = 0x04,
    OBJC_PR_readwrite = 0x08,
    OBJC_PR_retain    = 0x10,
    OBJC_PR_copy      = 0x20,
    OBJC_PR_nonatomic = 0x40,
    OBJC_PR_setter    = 0x80,
    OBJC_PR_atomic    = 0x100,
    OBJC_PR_weak      = 0x200,
    OBJC_PR_strong    = 0x400,
    OBJC_PR_unsafe_unretained = 0x800,
    /// Indicates that the nullability of the type was spelled with a
    /// property attribute rather than a type qualifier.
    OBJC_PR_nullability = 0x1000,
    OBJC_PR_null_resettable = 0x2000,
    OBJC_PR_class = 0x4000
    // Adding a property should change NumPropertyAttrsBits
  };

  enum {
    /// Number of bits fitting all the property attributes.
    NumPropertyAttrsBits = 15
  };
  /* Omitted */
};
```